How to refresh registers after monitor command
I use gdb with a remote target like
target extended-remote localhost:3333
cd project
file build/project.elf
monitor reset halt
load
print $pc

This works fine, the $pc points to the Reset_Handler
But after start and then break the program, I reset the target
monitor reset halt
print $pc
monitor reg pc

Now the $pc still shows the address where I breaked the program, instead of the Reset_Handler.
But the monitor reg pc shows the correct address (Reset_Handler).
After using next gdb updates the $pc and shows the correct value again.
The problem seems to be, that gdb does not update the registers after a monitor command.
If I reconnect to the target, the values are updated
target extended-remote localhost:3333
print $pc
monitor reg pc

But this seems to be a little bit of an overkill with possible side effects.
Is there any simple command or trick to reresh to the correct values of the registers?

Google was completely useless for this question (I wasted two days), but chat-GPT presented me the correct answer in an instant (I'm too old for this new stuff).
maintenance flush register-cache

